# Why am i getting always the same prediction value after reloading a saved and trained model for having new predictions?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I am a newbie in ML. I have a regression problem. The input layer consists of 7 Parameter. Output layer consists of 128 parameters (which are frequency bands) So I have trained my model and saved the model as well as input- and `outputScaler` (which is `MinMaxScaler` for scaling a new input array and retransforming the prediction)

After training, I want to give totally new input arrays without a pause. Just imagine like : we are having (1,7) shape of new inputs in every second. And I am forward them by one by to our loaded model.

```
loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model("model")

inputScaler = joblib.load(input_sc)
outputScaler = joblib.load(output_sc)


new_input = inputScaler.fit_transform(new_input )
prediction = loaded_model.predict(new_input )

inversed_predictData = outputScaler.inverse_transform(prediction)

sum_pred = np.sum(inversed_predictData, axis=1)
sum_pred
```

We are getting "new_input" in every second and aiming to get a new prediction `(sum_pred)`. But it returns always the first one.

I think the model has to be reset in some way.

I expect to get a different prediction values because I am feeding the model always with a new dataset. (Btw: some parameters have very similar values but still they are different.)

Comment: Could you share the convergence and other metric used while training the model for better evaluation of the situation at hand. There should not be any problem in predicting from the saved model.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar

`model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(25, activation='relu', input_dim=train_inputData.shape[-1]))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(200, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(150, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(train_outputData.shape[-1], activation='linear'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['accuracy'])
callback = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='accuracy', patience=3)
new_model = model.fit(train_inputData, train_outputData, epochs=50, batch_size=32, callbacks=[callback], verbose=2) `
```

Comment: There could be a problem with the model definition. Could you provide reproducible code along with the shape of `train_inputData` and `train_outputData` to replicate the error. Also, Please have a look at this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/regression), might be helpful. Thank you.